# Adding same click event handler to 2 different elements

Tags: events, event-handling, jquery

I have to elements `#addimage` and `#addimage_imgtab` that both need to be handled by the same function when clicked. I thought the following code should work, but it isn't, what am I doing wrong?

```
$('#addimage #addimage_imgtab').click(function(e){ .... });
```

Comment: The space is the *descendant selector*. You are looking for an element with ID `addimage_imgtab` *inside* an element with ID `addimage`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You forget a comma:

```
$('#addimage, #addimage_imgtab').click(function(e){ .... });
```